# Is real valued GA or binary valued GA used for practical purpose and latest implementations?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, heuristics, evolutionary-algorithm

I have recently started learning about heuristic optimization methods and started with genetic algorithm. I have understood the algorithm behind genetic algorithm. I have come across two types of GA which are Binary Coded GA and Real Valued GA. Everywhere, when I look for GA explanation and steps, I see about Binary Coded GA only. But when I look for GA and optimization libraries and packages, the mutation and cross over seems to be like real valued methods. Which of these methods is used in widely used and in practical purposes ? Please share if there's something that's incorrect in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what is different between binary GA and value-based GA.
you can find more details information in this paper.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261016773_A_Comparison_of_Binary_and_Continuous_Genetic_Algorithm_in_Parameter_Estimation_of_a_Logistic_Growth_Model

for binary GA better to use single or double-point crossover.
and you can use swap logic in mutation

```
   def binary_mutation(child1, child2):
        posi = random.randint(0, len(child1)-1)
        if child1[posi] == 1:
            child1[posi] = 0
        elif child1[posi] == 0:
            child1[posi] = 1
        if child2[posi] == 1:
            child2[posi] = 0
        elif child2[posi] == 0:
            child2[posi] = 1
        return child1, child2
```